# Not able to access data/partition on HDD after removing it from iMac

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, hdd

hope I'm right here. I'm quite lost as of now.

**tl;dr**

Can't properly access data from an **3 TB HDD** I removed from my dead iMac and hooked up **via USB (2.0)** to the new one.

- Recovery software tells me, I can save about 1 TB weirdly named files.
- Other software tells me, **2.2 TB are empty or unformatted.**

**EDIT** As I think of it, the empty/unformatted 2.2 TB are the exact size of my Google Drive DFS partition. So, I don't care about that anymore. But I would love to access the other 800 - 1.000 GB, which is currently not possible.

**Detailed version:**

My iMac died a few days ago. No more booting possible. So I removed the SSD and HDD, hooked the 3 TB HDD into (several different to be exactly) external USB cases but it's just not accessible anymore. Disk Utility tells me, the size is about **800 GB**. Several other Apps (Disk Drill, Paragon Recovery and some others) tell me, there is another **2.2 GB partition but it's empty or unformatted.**

[image]

I ran a deep scan with Disk Drill and there are about 1 TB on data I can recover. But it's a crazy mess without proper file names.

[image]

The most important data was synced with Google Drive via Google DFS, wich could explain the crazy mess of files, found in Disk Drill. The problem is, the iMac died 4 weeks after the last proper Time Machine Backup. Why, I don't know. So I would very much love to retrieve some data I downloaded in this timeframe, and if possible, some 320 carefully collected movies in MKV format. Disk Drill found all of them, but gave them extra funny names and serves it as .webm format. I randomly clicked on one file and found an episode of GoT.

[image]

So that seems like first world problems and I can live with the fact, that my movie collection is gone for good. But I have a feeling in my gut, that I forgot something important in some other folder where I dump files to sort them "later". Well.

So, any help in accessing the HDD in a normal way would be great. I tried Windows too.

**EDIT** As I think of it, the empty/unformatted 2.2 TB are the exact size of my Google Drive DFS partition. So, I don't care about that anymore. But I would love to access the other 800 - 1.000 GB, which is currently not possible.

Thank you all a million!

*EDIT: formatting*

Comment: I'd try a different USB enclosure first. Some remap the sector sizes in hardware which 'breaks' the drive if it wasn't already formatted in that enclosure.

Comment: Thanks, I tried about 6 of them. But I just added an explanation about the missing 2.2 TB. It's the Google DFS file system. So, that can be gone for good, because it's safe anyway.

Comment: I'd be tempted to let Disk Drill pull what it can to another drive, just in case things don't ever get any better, but  then I'd give [DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) a go.

Comment: The image you posted shows `Core Storage`. Did you have some sort of homemade Fusion drive involving the SSD and HDD?

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thanks for the tip regarding DiskWarrior, haven't tried that one. Will transfer the files found in Disk Drill tonight. Space is not the issue anyway.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - no homemade Fusion thing was done. I usually like to temper around with my machines, but I never made a Fusion drive. Thanks for talking part!